# What should be the value of si?

Tags: c, type-conversion

I am trying to workout the output of the below given c program but unable to figure out.

Why is si = 0?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void){

    float p = 1000;
    float r = 5;
    float t = 2;

    float si = p * r * t / 100;

    printf("SI = %d", si);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: `printf("SI = %d", si);` but `si` is a `float`: change to `%f`

Comment: `%d` is for **integers**

Comment: Why do you think `si` is `0`?

Comment: It should print the 4 bytes of float si by interpreting them as  an integer. If you want it to print 100 (or 99) then you can typecast `si` as `int` in the print statement.

Comment: good c beginners book needed. **this topic is the multiple duplicate**

Comment: Printf isn't that smart. You'll have to do the `(int)si` cast yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing value in floating point representation while you used `%d` specifier which forces printf to expect an `int`.

There is no 'automatic cast' when you pass variables to a variandic function like printf, the values are passed into the function as the datatype they actually are (or upgraded to a larger compatible type in some cases) because [c](/questions/tagged/c) is weakly typed language.

If you pass type with **incompatible internal representation** you will get garbage output.

Change

```
printf("SI = %d", si);
```

to

```
printf("SI = %f", si);
```

or (if you would like to get integral value of expression)

```
printf("SI = %d", (int)si);
```

Comment: any idea why is he getting 0 instead of expected garbage value?

Comment: @VikasYadav Consider: I send you a `float` and put it in the `float` box.  You look in the `int` box and see ... nothing  .... and print that. Perhaps a 0 left over from before, maybe not, maybe the boxes overlap?  It is _undefined behavior_.